# laravel php str_replace function replace 2 different values with 2 different values

Tags: php, laravel, str-replace

So in my php file, i request the price from the registration table. And in the html i want to fill in a value 2,50. So i thought i'd use str_replace for that(replace the "," with "."), but i also want to replace "€ " with "". I'm not sure how to do that.
I have tried doing 1 at a time, and that worked fine.
Here some code i have right now:

**My php code**

```
$registration->reg_price = str_replace('€ ', '', $request->price);
$registration->save();
```

Any help will be much appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$registration->reg_price = str_replace(['€', ' ', ','], ['', '', '.'], $request->price);
```

Just beware of '€ ', much better break in '€' and ' '.

Answer (score 1):

```
$registration->reg_price = str_replace(['€ ', ','], ['', '.'], $request->price);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$registration->reg_price = str_replace('€', '', $request->price);
$registration->reg_price = str_replace(',', '.', $registration->reg_price);
```

`str_replace` returns the string, you can apply string replacement on the updated string.

**OR**

you can send arrays as parameters like this:

```
$string = str_replace(
    array("search","replace1"),
    array("search2", "replace2"),
    $string
);
```